# Behavior of buggy parameter passing

Tags: python, parameter-passing

I have a function:

```
def greeter(name, greeting, punc):
    print greeting+', '+name+punc
```

I have a dictionary with parameters:

```
params={'name':'Mark','greeting':'How are you','punc':'?'}
```

When I call the function as `greeter(**params)`, I get the expected output `How are you, Mark?`. But When I call like this `greeter(*params)`, I get the output `name, puncgreeting`. Looks like a list of keys from `params` has been passed to `greeter`. What is actually happening here?

Just curious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Looks like a list of keys from params has been passed to greeter. What is actually happening here?

That is indeed what is happening, more or less.

`*x` expects `x` to be an iterable, and iterates over it, interpreting the results as arguments one by one. Iterating over a dict, by default, iterates over its keys. (You could get name/value pairs instead, for example, with `greeter(*(params.items()))`, but the dict would still be unsorted so order of iteration would be unreliable.)

Answer (score 2):

Just as iterating over a dict yields keys, so does using it in positional expansion in this manner.

```
print list(params)
```